# Syntax shell scripting? "word unexpected in" getopts

Tags: shell, getopts, ubuntu-8.04

Good evening everybody, We're looking forward to execute a shell script on an Ubuntu 8.04, But it returns a special error:

```
line 14: Word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

So here is a preview of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#Declaration of shell parameters
A3REP=""
A3FILE=""
A3HELP=""
A3PORT="80"
A3PORTTC="80"
A3IP400=""
A3USER=""
A3PWD=""
A3TASK=""
while getopts d:f:h:p:i:u:w:t:n: option
do 
  case $option in
    d)
    A3REP="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    f)  
    A3FILE="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    p)  
    A3PORT="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    t)  
    A3PORTTC="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    i)  
    A3IP400="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    u)  
    A3USER="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    w)  
    A3PWD="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    n)  
    A3TASK="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    h)
    A3HELP="aide"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
the script was in dos:

insert the following line in d2u.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1|tr -d '\015'
```

and now execute :

```
chmod +x d2u.sh
```

now the script is ready to run.

Try this script typing the following command:

```
sh d2u.sh filename.sh > filename2.sh
```

and the script isn't in dos anymore.

Thank you everybody! :)

Comment: The syntax looks fine.  Perhaps your line endings are fubar.  Provide a hex dump of lines 13-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a problem with line endings, try

```sh
d2u FILE
```

[**ref**](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=1871)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! We didn't know what D2U Meant, and after some research we came to try a scrit, if anyone is searching, Here is the things to do in the first post :